# Environment variable getting unset everytime terminal session is closed

Tags: linux, maven, centos, environment-variables

Iam new to linux , and trying to run some maven commands . My environment file content is follows -

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME
M2_HOME=/home/sam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$M2_HOME
export PATH
```

However whenever i run mvn related stuff once in a terminal and close it and reopen a new session , iam unable to run mvn commands , and i get "not a command " error .

Could any one help me how to rectify it so that i dont see this error again and again and the variables set permanently .

Comment: First only settings the path of Maven through `PATH=$PATH:/home/sam/Download/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin` and maybe you can add JAVA_HOME as well but don't use `M2_HOME`...Apart from that this is more a general Linux question cause you need to do this kind of setup either in `/etc/profiles` or in the users `$HOME/.profiles` or depending on what kind of shell you use `$HOME/.bash_profile`?.

Comment: @khmarbaise , i couldn't get you , could you please rephrase ur answer .

Answer (score 1):

You need to set path for java and maven.

You can do one thing add your path code

**JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME
M2_HOME=/home/sam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$M2_HOME
export PATH**

into

**~/.bashrc**  File.

This file is execute every time when you open your terminal. 
So once you write your export path text in this file it will remain set for all the time.

It is very simple to write your path in **~/.bashrc** File.

1. Open Your terminal
2. vi ~/.bashrc
3. .bashrc is Open now.
4. Just press page-down button and go to the last line of the file.
5. Copy your path code 
         *JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk export JAVA_HOME

         M2_HOME=/home/sam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9 export M2_HOME

         PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$M2_HOME export PATH*
6. Press shift+i so you can add text in this file
7. Now at the end of file just paste your code using **ctrl+shift+v**
8. Now Save file, press Escape then shift+colon  you can see colon (:) at 
   end of terminal. Then Press wq  so it will display like :wq
9. Now press enter.

That's it.

Now close the terminal and reopen it. You can test your updated path is working or not using "mvn".

Comment: check below command is working in terminal for one time use? then try above method.

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk export JAVA_HOME M2_HOME=/home/sam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9 export M2_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$M2_HOME export PATH